# Can't build Unity app using App Bundle for android. File uses reserved file or directory name 'res'

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have to build android app using Unity 2018.4.9f1 with App Bundle (Google play) and I get this error. When building normal apk everything is working fine.

**1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.**

Tried diffrent unity versions. Tried deleting this file (but looks like it's hidden somewhere or generating during gradle compile)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Unity 2019.4.0f1 and got stuck in the same error. Here's what I've found on internet and solved.

(you probably got a solution, but it's good for those who will see this post)

Open your **project settings > Player > Other Settings**, loko for **configuration**, make sure you ticked this options below:

[Player setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc2cz.png)

- Scripting Backend **IL2CPP**
- Enable **ARMv7, ARM64, Split APKs by target architecture**

Then in your **Build Settings**

[Build settings setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2gYW.png)

Just default values (unity 2019.4 version).

Hope that helps someone :)

[edit 1]

I know this doesn't fix the android bundle app build, I think that's an unity bug, not sure, however this should work fine on google play console (worked for me)